# FB like is not working

Tags: facebook-like

I am having an issue with FaceBook "like". I have created a site in Drupal 6 where anonymous user can't see a page until he logs in.

I have added FaceBook "like" code. but it is not working.

URL : http://www.essentialsharm.co.uk/user
user name : dipali
password : 123456

Please help me asap.

Comment: Please supply the relevant code

Comment: are you posting a username and password?

Comment: in head , 
<?php $curr_url = check_plain("http://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  ?>
  <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $head_title; ?>" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="essentialsharm:page" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="190417014424616"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $curr_url; ?>" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="image path here"  />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Essential Sharm" />

Comment: in body
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=190417014424616";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://essentialsharm.co.uk/news" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="80" data-show-faces="false"></div>

Comment: Yes I am entering this site using user name and password.

Answer (score 0):

Like Buttons don´t work if the data you want to like is only available with a user login. The Page has to be accessible for Facebook, so it can read the Open Graph Tags correctly.

I guess you used the generator, if not:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/